# Complicated contour integral to be solved.

Tags: integration, contour-integration, complex-integration

Anyone can help to solve the following integral?

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty} dp p^{-1}e^{-2p^{2}M^{-2}}\sin(pr)\frac{M^2}{M^2+p^2}$$

at this stage I am able to write the integral as

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty} dp p^{-1}e^{-2p^{2}M^{-2}}\frac{M^2(\exp (i p r)-\exp (-i p r))}{2i(p+iM)(p-iM)}$$

if the integral was without $p^{-1}e^{-2p^{2}M^{-2}}$ part, one could use the general contour integral formula. But now things are not as simple. So the question is how to solve the integral?

---

**Note**: $M > 0$ and $r > 0$ (i.e. +ve constants)

Comment: What exactly is M?

Comment: M and r are are constants and >0. thanks for mentioning

Comment: First of all you can simplify it by taking $q = p/M$ to get $I = \int_0^\infty dq \frac{e^{-2q^2}}{1+q^2} \frac{\sin(qMr)}{q}$. It seems like a hard integral to solve (except in the limit $Mr\to \infty$ where we find $I \to \frac{\pi}{2}$).

Comment: I outline the evaluation of such an integral in this solution to a partial differential equation; see the Addendum to the solution.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456504/advection-diffusion-equation-on-semi-infinite-domain/457668#457668

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adopting @Winther's suggestion, substitute $q=p/M$ and write $R=Mr$, so the integral we seek is
$$ I(R) = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-2q^2} \frac{\sin{Rq}}{q} \frac{dq}{1+q^2}. $$
Then
$$ -I'''(R) + I'(R) = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-2q^2} \cos{Rq} \, dq \tag{1} $$

The integral on the right can be done by the usual methods (more differentiation under the integral sign, for example, or completing the square &c.) to give $ \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8}} e^{-R^2/8} $. Integrating from $0$ to $R$, $I''(0)=I(0)=0$, so
$$ -I''(R)+I(R) = \frac{\pi}{2} \operatorname{erf}{\left( R/\sqrt{8} \right)} $$

A basis of solutions is given by $ u_1(R) = e^R $ and $u_2(R) = e^{-R}$, and so the Wronskian is -2, and variation of parameters gives
$$ I(R) = \int_0^R \frac{1}{2}(-e^{R-r}+e^{r-R}) \frac{\pi}{2} \operatorname{erf}{\left( r/\sqrt{8} \right)} \, dr + A\sinh{R} \\
= -\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^R \sinh{(R-r)} \operatorname{erf}{\left( r/\sqrt{8} \right)} \, dr + A\sinh{R}
$$

$$ A=I'(0) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-2q^2}}{1+q^2} \, dq = \frac{e^2\pi}{2}(1-\operatorname{erf}(\sqrt{2})) $$
(this can be computed using the Schwinger parametrisation, for example.)

The final integral can be done using integration by parts repeatedly (or interchanging the order of integration), and we end up with the final answer
$$ I(R) = \frac{e^2\pi}{4} \sinh{R} -\frac{e^2\pi}{4} e^{-R} \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{R-4}{\sqrt{8}}\right)+\frac{\pi}{2}  \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{R}{\sqrt{8}}\right)-\frac{e^2\pi}{4}  e^{R} \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{R+4}{\sqrt{8}}\right) $$

---

**Edited to add:** One can find the differential equation as follows: notice that
$$ \frac{d}{dR} \sin{Rq} = q\cos{Rq}, $$
so one differentiation under the integral sign gets rid of the $q^{-1}$. I still didn't much fancy evaluating
$$ I'(R) = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-2q^2} \cos{Rq} \frac{dq}{1+q^2}, $$
so I then used that
$$ \left( -\frac{d^2}{dR^2} + 1 \right) \cos{Rq} = (q^2+1)\cos{Rq} $$
to get rid of the $\frac{1}{1+q^2}$, which gives the equation (1).

Now, to evaluate
$$ J = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-2q^2} \cos{Rq} \, dq = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-2q^2} e^{iRq} \, dq, $$
we could look in a table of Fourier transforms, or complete the square:
$$ -2q^2 + iRq = -2\left( q - \frac{iR}{4} \right)^2 - \frac{R^2}{8}, $$
and then we have a standard Gaussian integral times $e^{-R^2/8}$. (We do need to shift the integration contour back to the real line, of course.)

Comment: Very nice solution! Deserves some more upvotes, i think...:)

Comment: Nice solution! And also a good example of a problem where humans beats computers (Mathematica, for example, is not able to solve it):)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @cheppers ok I re-derived most of the parts, can you please elaborate on this part please:

A basis of solutions is given by $ u_1(R) = e^R $ and $u_2(R) = e^{-R}$, and so the Wronskian is -2, and variation of parameters gives
$$ I(R) = \int_0^R \frac{1}{2}(-e^{R-r}+e^{r-R}) \frac{\pi}{2} \operatorname{erf}{\left( r/\sqrt{8} \right)} \, dr + A\sinh{R} \\
= -\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^R \sinh{(R-r)} \operatorname{erf}{\left( r/\sqrt{8} \right)} \, dr + A\sinh{R}
$$

$$ A=I'(0) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-2q^2}}{1+q^2} \, dq = \frac{e^2\pi}{2}(1-\operatorname{erf}(\sqrt{2})) $$
(this can be computed using the Schwinger parametrisation, for example.)

The final integral can be done using integration by parts repeatedly (or interchanging the order of integration), and we end up with the final answer
$$ I(R) = \frac{e^2\pi}{4} \sinh{R} -\frac{e^2\pi}{4} e^{-R} \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{R-4}{\sqrt{8}}\right)+\frac{\pi}{2}  \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{R}{\sqrt{8}}\right)-\frac{e^2\pi}{4}  e^{R} \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{R+4}{\sqrt{8}}\right) $$